# MVC Entity Framework computed value that exists in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have used entity framework to generate models from my existing database and I want to compute the value for a property. e.g.

I have a MetaInfo table:

- PageTitle, string, not nullable
- MetaTitle, string, nullable

So I've constructed a partial class:

```
public partial class MetaInfo
{
    public string MetaTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MetaTitle))
            {
                return _PageTitle;
            }
            return _MetaTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work though because 'The type MetaInfo already contains a definition for MetaTile'.

Is there a way to do this maintaining the same property name or should I just rename my computed property?

While I'm here, could I do some wiza-ma-jig and get code first to integrate with my existing database and would it circumvent this problem?

Comment: The [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d?SRC=Featured) should let you reverse-engineer a code-first model from an existing database. (Not sure whether Code First will let you do the mapping you need though, but you should be able to customise the name of the mapped field/property at least.)

Comment: I think you need to add another layer of Models somewhere. Are you trying to use your Entity classes directly in your views? If so, you should create ViewModels specific for you views. These will have almost the same properties as you auto-generated classes but you can add extra methods (or alter the properties) as you wish. For example, add a function called `GetPageTitle()` which checks the `MetaTitle` value and does whatever you need

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity classes in my views I think with the Meta Data/Data Annotations/Validation help in entity framework it wouldn't be economical to code up separate view models, it's not very DRY either imo. For now until I find a better solution I'm going with a getter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention `MetaTitle` will be the column name from the database and I don't think there is an easy way of getting round the issue you describe other than using a different name for your computed property, something like `DisplayMetaTitle`, `FriendlyMetaTitle` or `ViewMetaTitle` is quite common.

Comment: Yeah, I know they're mapped to the column names. I don't know if a single data and view model is the best solution or even possible - but I would like it to be :) This is the solution I'm going with until I find a better one anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: It's often advisable to have a separate view model or DTO, especially if you are using something like the repository pattern, it allows you to keep your data layer separate from the logic.  It all too easy to EF to be hammering the database without realising it and having a repository that loads the data into a DTO can help when locating performance issues.  But nothing inherently wrong with using the entity as a view model for smaller programs.